# Using list comprehensions, write a script that subtracts a list's element from list to list

Tags: python

I am trying to subtract elements from a list in a list of lists using list comprehension.
I want to achieve something like:

```py
list1=[a,b,c]

listoflist=[[e,f,g,h],[i,j],[k,l,m,n]]

new_list= [[e-a,f-a,g-a,h-a],[i-b,j-b],[k-c,l-c,m-c,n-c]]
```

So it is an element to element subtraction but either get errors because most of my numbers are floats or I get something like:

```py
new_list= [[[e,a],[f,b],[g,c]],[[i,a],[j,b]...]
```

I don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
new_list = [[v1 - v2 for v1 in vs1] for v2, vs1 in zip(list1, listoflists)]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Your answer was clear and concise. Thank you again. I will definitely save this somewhere, I am new to Python, and list comprehension throws me off sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

zip will create tuple for corresponding elements in each list.
Then do list comprehension to subtract second element from first element for each tuple.

```
 [ x-y for x, y in list(zip(list1,list2))]
```